# How to add only date like 'DD/MM/YYYY' to timestamp in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, date, datetime

I'm trying to add only the current date in "DD/MM/YYYY" format in a field of type ' timestamp in PostgreSQL' .

I try:

```
select to_char(now(),'DD/MM/YYYY') as date;
```

But PostgreSQL return me:

TIP : You will need to rewrite the expression or apply a type conversion.

Comment: What version is this? The given query works in Postgres 9.4.

Comment: I use postgres 9.5

Comment: `select current_date`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as "only the date" in a `timestamp` field. A timestamp field will store timestamps.

Try using the `date` type instead. Please read about this [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html).

Also, please consider using the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format instead. Getting used to it helps in a lot of cases.
Human-readable formats like "DD/MM/YYYY" should only be used for presentation.

If you want to use timestamp fields and insert a human-readable formatted dates, then you are looking for:

```
to_timestamp('05/04/2016', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

If it is about the current date, then Postgres provides the [CURRENT_DATE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT) function, which you may use:

```
SELECT CURRENT_DATE;
INSERT INTO t (timestamp_field) VALUES (CURRENT_DATE);
```

Comment: Hello @Anthony Drogon, but, can I put the date like 'DD/MM/YYYY 00:00:00' ?

Comment: Yes, this is a valid input for a timestamp, look at section 8.5.1.3 in the provided link.
Although, if you insert the value's date part as a 'DD/MM/YYYY' formatted string, Postgres will treat it by default as the American MDY, except you started postgres with the '-e' option, which sets the default format to DMY.
Using to_timestamp('05/04/2016', 'DD/MM/YYYY') is a way to achieve what you want then.
Edited the answer.

Comment: But @Anthony Drogon, I try to insert a new date with the query: select to_timestamp (now(), 'DD/MM/YYYY' ); and postgres return me: "If you want to use timestamp fields and insert a human-readable formatted dates, then you are looking for"

Comment: If it is only about the current date, with the time part set to "00:00:00", in a timestamp field, then Postgres provides the "CURRENT_DATE" function. Try "SELECT CURRENT_DATE", then inserting "CURRENT_DATE" in your timestamp field. Is that the behavior you expected?

Comment: Glad I could help, sorry it took so much time to understand what you wanted to achieve. I updated the answer accordingly, please accept it to show the community this question has been answered :) Thank you.